# How to pass a variable between Index/Show to Order page in Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

So I'm using a mix of Ruby/jQuery/JavaScript to pass information from my Index/Show pages to the Order page. In my Index/Show view I have the following:

```
<%= link_to 'Get a Collectible', order_books_path(:id => book.id), class: "btn merch%>
```

Then in my Order view I have:

```
<div class="image-container <%= 'active' if books.id == params[:id].to_i%>" image-var="<%books.book_image%>">
<%= image_tag books.book_image, class: "book-image" %>
```

Great so I'm passing the books id if clicked to the order page to then mark said book as active. To read it through and maintain the changes on the page for what's "active" I'm using the following JS for parsing:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url)
        url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results)
        return null;
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Then the following jQuery for changing on the Order page:

```
var $link = $('.img-container1');
        $('.img-group').on('click', '.img-container1', function() {
            $link.removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('input[name="image"]').val(this.getAttribute('image-var')).change();
        });

        var type = getParameterByName('type');
        var image = getParameterByName('image');
```

And finally in jQuery for changing the transfer from the Show page to the Order page:

```
$(function() {
            $('div [button_type="' + type + '"]').addClass('btn wk-prd-btn pink');
            $('div [image-var="' + image + '"]').addClass('active');
            $('input[name="image"]').val(image).change();
        });
```

So that's all the code. It operates perfectly fine except I need to pass the image-var to HubSpot for image selection. I inspected the page and sure enough it's not passing the image-var. So I made a change here:

```
<div class="image-container <%= 'active' if books.id == params[:id].to_i%>" image-var="<%books.book_image.to_s%>">
```

I added in .to_s at the end and sure enough the image text comes through but without capitalization and it loses it's .jpg at the end (which is being used).

So how do I maintain/pass the variable between views that I can then pass along?

Answer (score 0):

So much rage. The answer is actually outputting the variable. So

```
image-var="<%=books.book_image.to_s%>">
```